# Getting Cognito ID from API Gateway, and Lambda

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS Cognito, API Gateway, Lambdas and react.js (which is my first time to use them). Currently I'm working on implementing the signup/in pages. I managed to authenticate the user with Cognito, send the access code with the URL as a header to the secured API Gateway to grant access. This all working fine for me. My problem is, How to get the Cognito ID from the access token sent from the front end (using React.js) through API Gateway and receive it in my Lambda, to know the ID of the user who just signed in??

I found some people talking about Mapping template in API Gateway Integration Request, but I have no idea how to use this?? and what shall I write in my lambda to see the code!! The AWS Docs doesn't give clear example about this !!

Any help with the code please !!

Answer (score 3):

If you Use Lambda Proxy integration you can access user information through the requestContext path.

```
event.requestContext.authorizer.claims
```

In here you'll have a claims body similar to this

```
{
    "sub": "gae4t3qha-ha4g-j4as-12fa-gag42aerh34",
    "cognito:groups": "group1,group2",
    "email_verified": "true",
    "cognito:preferred_role": "arn:aws:iam::12345677890:role/role1",
    "iss": "https://cognito-idp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-userpoolId2gw3e4",
    "cognito:username": "example@email.com",
    "cognito:roles": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/role1,arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/service-role/role2",
    "aud": "ga32qah34wjk4trujnsa4hy",
    "event_id": "0491fe1c-6eff-4220-ae93-582588e2af0e",
    "token_use": "id",
    "auth_time": "1564962329",
    "exp": "Mon Aug 05 00:45:29 UTC 2019",
    "iat": "Sun Aug 04 23:45:29 UTC 2019",
    "email": "example@email.com" 
  }
```

claims.sub acts as Cognito's UUID for each user